# supabase onAuthStateChange not re-rendering useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, supabase

I have the following custom hook `useAuth`, in which I am having a `supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange` event listener.

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState(supabase.auth.session());

  const signOutUser = async () => {
    await supabase.auth.signOut();
    useAuthStore.setState({
      user: null,
    });
    setSession(null);
  };

   useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ session });
  }, [session]);

  supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => {
    if (session) {      
      const { error: fetchError, data } = await fetchUser(session);
      if (fetchError) {
        await signOutUser();
      } else {
        if (data.length === 0) {         
          setSession(session);            
        } else {            
          setSession(session);            
        }
      }      
    } else {
      setSession(null);
    }
  }); 

  return session;
};
```

Now I am using `react-router-dom@6` for routing.

This is my `App.js` file

```
function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const session = useAuth();
  let location = useLocation();

  console.log({ children, session });

  if (!session) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }

  return children;
}

function App() {  
  return (    
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <Home />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />        
        <Route
          path="/servers"
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <Servers />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route path="*" element={<FourNotFour />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Now my question is within `useAuth` i have a line like `console.log({ session });` which prints out session object, but this line is getting printed only once, even after the auth state has changed to logged in, and `setSession` got executed. And thus on `App.js` file the method `RequireAuth` keep on executing only once thus after login my app is still on the login page, it's not re-routing to `Home` page

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your auth listener inside of a `useEffect` so you can react to changes.
`onAuthStateChange` returns the listener, which you can unsubscribe from in the `useEffect`'s cleanup function:

```ts
useEffect(() => {
  const { data: authListener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
    async (event, session) => {
      if (session) {
        const { error: fetchError, data } = await fetchUser(session);
        if (fetchError) {
          await signOutUser();
        } else {
          if (data.length === 0) {
            setSession(session);
          } else {
            setSession(session);
          }
        }
      } else {
        setSession(null);
      }
    }
  );

  // cleanup function to unsubscribe
  return () => {
    if (authListener) authListener.unsubscribe();
  };
}, [supabase.auth]);
```

Comment: still no way, the `RequireAuth` is getting rendered once, and the value of session is that of `null`

Comment: also the event listener just cleans up subscription the very first time